# How to parse JSON which has escaped quotes with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have following JSON
`[{\"X\":24.0124010872935,\"Y\":49.7740722529036,\"Code\":\"0320\",\"Name\": .....]`

I try to parse it as

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(response.body(), RouteModel[].class)
```

And got Exception

`Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 3 path $[0].`

**EDIT**
So far the best solution was to add
`compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'` dependency and use `gson.fromJson(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(response.body()), RouteModel[].class)`

Or just simply use `replace("\\\"","\"")`

Comment: wouldn't replacing it work?  `gson.fromJson(response.body().replaceAll("\\\"","\"")`

Comment: @nafas Thanks. Yep that works, but Im wondering if I can do this without such workaround. And this is correct `replaceAll("\\\\\"","\"")` or `replace("\\\"","\"")`

Comment: to be honest mate, if was you I would have checked why my server post content are like that.  there is something wrong .most likely  client sending you bad format.. PS I checked Jordi's answer. it worked for me(after changing your input to a `valid` JSON but escaped `"`).

Comment: @nafas Unfortunately I cannot change server response. And what do you mean "(after changing your input to a `valid` JSON but escaped `"`)"

Answer (score 2):

Using `disableHtmlEscaping` should solve the problem without ugly workarounds.
Also I used `prettyPrinting` to have a nicer output....

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
gson.from(response.body(), RouteModel[].class)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but it seems that this doesn't work, I got the same error. And `setPrettyPrinting` only affects Json serialization. But I try to parse JSON to Java object.

Comment: This is it!  disableHtmlEscaping() will remove all the \ from the Json payload.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, welcome to the gorgeous world of the SimpleRide API. :D I had happy-fun-coding time when I tried to solve that problem for the first time a year and half ago before launching my Android app. I suspect that those guys return such a string in order to use `JSON.parse` in the front-side only. Therefore the *easiest* (but not the most efficient) way is parsing responses as strings to "normalize" them and then parsing normalized JSON documents.

In order to parse *your* (see the comments below) JSON, there is a need to represent your JSON input stream as a JSON string literal input stream. This can be done easily by concatenating input streams.

```java
final class FixedInputStreams {

    private static final byte[] e1DoubleQuoteArray = "\"".getBytes();

    private FixedInputStreams() {
    }

    static InputStream fixInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
        return concatInputStreams(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(e1DoubleQuoteArray),
                inputStream,
                new ByteArrayInputStream(e1DoubleQuoteArray)
        );
    }

    private static InputStream concatInputStreams(final InputStream... inputStreams) {
        return concatInputStreams(asList(inputStreams).iterator());
    }

    // Iterator and not an iterable by design
    private static InputStream concatInputStreams(final Iterator<? extends InputStream> inputStreamsIterator) {
        return new SequenceInputStream(asEnumeration(inputStreamsIterator));
    }

    private static <T> Enumeration<T> asEnumeration(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
        return new Enumeration<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasMoreElements() {
                return iterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public T nextElement() {
                return iterator.next();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

What this class does is only fixing such a malformed input stream in order to simulate a JSON string input stream. Thus, with the input stream above, your JSON becomes a legal JSON string:

> [{\"X\":24.0124010872935,\"Y\":49.7740722529036,\"Code\":\"0320\",\"Name\": .....]

→

> "[{\"X\":24.0124010872935,\"Y\":49.7740722529036,\"Code\":\"0320\",\"Name\": .....]"

Now you have to parse this string to extract the normalized JSON. `MalformedJsonTypeAdapterFactory` represents a synthetic Gson type adapter factory and it's only responsibility is parsing JSON string literals and then parse the latter to well-formed DTOs.

```java
final class StringWrapperTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final Gson realGson;

    private StringWrapperTypeAdapterFactory(final Gson realGson) {
        this.realGson = realGson;
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getStringWrapperTypeAdapterFactory(final Gson realGson) {
        return new StringWrapperTypeAdapterFactory(realGson);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public T read(final JsonReader in) {
                final String jsonDocument = realGson.fromJson(in, String.class);
                return realGson.fromJson(jsonDocument, typeToken.getType());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

So the idea here is:

> "[{\"X\":24.0124010872935,\"Y\":49.7740722529036,\"Code\":\"0320\",\"Name\": .....]"

→

> [{"X":24.0124010872935,"Y":49.7740722529036,"Code":"0320","Name": .....]

A sample DTO class similar to what I have in my application source code:

```java
final class NamedPoint {

    @SerializedName("X")
    final double longitude = Double.valueOf(0); // disabling primitives inlining

    @SerializedName("Y")
    final double latitude = Double.valueOf(0);

    @SerializedName("Code")
    final String code = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return '<' + code + "=(" + latitude + ',' + longitude + ")>";
        //                   ^__ See? Even this string is aware of the issue
    }

}
```

Finally, the general configuration and workflow now become as it follows:

```java
static final Type namedPointListType = new TypeToken<List<NamedPoint>>() {
}.getType();

static final Gson realGson = new GsonBuilder()
        // ... your Gson configuration here ...
        .create();

static final Gson stringWrapperGson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(getStringWrapperTypeAdapterFactory(realGson))
        .create();
```

```java
// or `new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonSource.getBytes())` to test quickly
final InputStream malformedInputStream = ...;
try ( final InputStream fixedInputStream = fixInputStream(malformedInputStream);
        final Reader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fixedInputStream))) {
    final List<NamedPoint> namedPoints = stringWrapperGson.fromJson(jsonReader, namedPointListType);
    out.println(namedPoints);
}
```

The output:

> [<0320=(49.7740722529036,24.0124010872935)>]

A couple of comments regarding the SimpleRide API:

- I'm not sure if you need "fixing" input streams by `"`-concatenation now, because the API seems to wrap it up itself (due to `JSON.parse`?). You can check it easily with something like `wget http://82.207.107.126:13541/SimpleRide/LAD/SM.WebApi/api/Schedule/?routeId=713032&code=0298`. Maybe a certain `Content-Type` can adjust the responses format?
- Since `StringWrapperTypeAdapterFactory` creates an intermediate string to be parsed in further steps, it may be not efficient due to memory costs. To overcome this issue and reduce the size of consumed memory during the parsing, you could write a custom `InputStream` or `Reader` that could be JSON-aware and strip the escaping characters themselves, so you wouldn't even need `StringWrapperTypeAdapterFactory` and intermediate strings.

## Edit:

As it was said above, streaming fashioned style is better for such parsing in order to save memory from unnecessary intermediate objects. Despite, `InputStream` is not a very appropriate place to read *character data* and `Reader` fits such a task better, simple JSON-escaping `InputStream` is easier to implement:

```
final class StringWrapperInputStream
        extends InputStream {

    private final InputStream inputStream;

    private State state = State.PRE_INIT;

    private StringWrapperInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    static InputStream getStringWrapperInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
        return new StringWrapperInputStream(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public int read()
            throws IOException {
        for ( ; ; ) {
            switch ( state ) {
            case PRE_INIT:
                final int chPreInit = inputStream.read();
                if ( chPreInit == -1 ) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if ( isWhitespace(chPreInit) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ( chPreInit == '\"' ) {
                    state = IN_PROGRESS;
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("char=" + chPreInit);
                }
                continue;
            case IN_PROGRESS:
                final int chInProgress1 = inputStream.read();
                if ( chInProgress1 == -1 ) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if ( chInProgress1 == '\"' ) {
                    state = DONE;
                    continue;
                }
                if ( chInProgress1 != '\\' ) {
                    return chInProgress1;
                }
                final int chInProgress2 = inputStream.read();
                if ( chInProgress2 == -1 ) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if ( chInProgress2 == '\"' ) {
                    return '\"';
                }
                break;
            case DONE:
                return -1;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError(state);
            }
        }
    }

    enum State {

        PRE_INIT,
        IN_PROGRESS,
        DONE

    }

}
```